# How do I get the number of copies from a print job?

Tags: windows, delphi, printing

I need to get number of copies of a print job. I have its information in a `JOB_INFO_1` record, but there is not any field for number of copies. How can I get this value?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Instead of JOB_INFO_1, you will need to get a JOB_INFO_2 structure, which has a pointer to a DEVMODE structure, that in turn has a number of copies field. JOB_INFO_2 can be retrieved using GetJob, just as JOB_INFO_1.

Comment: I've searching about how to use that in c# and I didn't found anything, can I do it in c#???, help me with a example

Comment: i also need a help regarding this matter... please provide some step by step if anyone succeed...

Comment: @gumuruh an karelp90 - This is a question for Delphi. I'm not sure if recent versions of .NET have a more abstract wrapper for handling print jobs, but there are various questions on SO and elsewhere about this Win32 API version. A common problem seems to be the incorrect definition of the required JOB_INFO_2 struct. Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8082445/setjob-method-always-returns-122) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47564653/why-get-wrong-total-page-of-n-up-printing-using-win32-printjob-c), for similar questions but for C#.

Comment: thanks @GolezTrol... now i got the JOB_INFO_2 details along with the pointer of DEVMODE only. So how do I load the pointer become an Object properties....  thanks for the suggestions anyway! :D