# Windows API: Should I always use 'W' variants of functions, or is 'A' applicable too?

Tags: python, function, winapi

I'm writing a program in Python and in one of my functions is a call to the **GetWindowText** function to get the title text of the current window. I don't know too much about the Windows API just yet, but I do understand that the 'A' variant of functions is ANSI and the 'W' variants is Wide per MSDN.

My question is, do I always want to utilize 'W' nowadays, i.e. **GetWindowTextW**, and why exactly if so? I've done some research but I can't seem to fully understand what's wrong with using 'A'. Is it just legacy now and programmers have naturally moved onto 'W', or is it bad practice because it causes issues with your code down the line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Always use W (unicode) versions unless you really don't want to for some reason (some more recent APIs don't even have A versions). 
This is documented here: [Conventions for Function Prototypes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/intl/conventions-for-function-prototypes). I quote:

> New Windows applications should use Unicode to avoid the
>   inconsistencies of varied code pages and for ease of localization.
>   They should be written with generic functions, and should define
>   UNICODE to compile the functions into Unicode functions. In the few
>   places where an application must work with 8-bit character data, it
>   can make explicit use of the functions for Windows code pages.

Comment: There are at least 2 more reasons to explicitly call the wide-character version of the Windows API: Arguments aren't subject to character set conversions (and thus arbitrary buffer limitations), and your code doesn't rely on preprocessor symbols. The latter is useful if you want to include a header that's a bit more conservative about symbol pollution than `Windows.h`. Besides that, the Windows API now supports experimental UTF-8 support for the formerly-known-as-ANSI API versions. That may turn out to be useful when interfacing with Python.

Comment: [Basic information about UTF-8 codepage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/globalizing/use-utf8-code-page), available since Windows Version 1903 (May 2019 Update).