# Why get wrong total page of N-Up printing using Win32_PrintJob/C#?

Tags: c#, printing, wmi, printers

I'm working on a program in C# to pause and get the total page count when printing, here is main code:

```
string wql = "SELECT * FROM Win32_PrintJob";
ManagementObjectCollection mos;
Dictionary<uint,short> checkedJobs = new Dictionary<uint,short>();

while (true)
{
      Thread.Sleep(SleepTime);
      try
      {
           mos = new ManagementObjectSearcher(wql).Get();
           if (mos != null && mos.Count > 0)
           {
                foreach (ManagementObject mo in mos)
                {
                    if (mo != null)
                    {
                        uint jobId = ProcessJob(mo);
                        if (!checkedJobs.ContainsKey(jobId))
                            checkedJobs.Add(jobId, 0);
                        }
                    }                        
                }
                // ...
           }
      }
```

It works fine with normal task.But in N-Up printing ,when I print more than one slides in one page(N Slides-In-One Page), it comes wrong, I can not get the right total count to print.

Is there anyone who ever meet this question~please help,many thanks

Comment: How are you getting the page count, and what is "wrong"?

Comment: The result is wrong means(Only in the mode of N-Up printing), for example,I print a ppt of 10 page;But I print the ppt of 5-in-1 mode(print 5 slides in one page).The total page should be 2, but it comes to 10.

Comment: And I get the total page by using JOB_INFO_2.TotalPages

Comment: You should really provide as much info as possible in your question. You don't tell us the apps you are testing with. Is it a Google Slides doc or something else? Which apps work and which cause problems? What are the results?

Comment: the app as the printing source is not the problem @NickWestgate,... coz the problem is obtaining the information while printing occured, he got the incorrect data in the end.

Comment: @gumuruh: The app and driver can be relevant. See my answer below, and my other answer I link to there.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is similar to another question (see my [answer there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47064399/313445) and follow the link for more info) but perhaps it's different enough to warrant a different answer here.

Basically NUP is not supported by all print drivers. The application you're using may be checking the [DEVMODE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183565(v=vs.85).aspx) (or ignoring it) and handling NUP by itself rather than [letting the Spooler handle it](https://www.experts-exchange.com/articles/2090/How-to-set-Pages-Per-Sheet-Programmatically-for-N-Up-Printing.html).

As I said in the other answer, the Windows page count can't be relied on for all apps and drivers. This might improve with the new XPS print system, but for old apps and drivers the only way to get a reliable page count is to parse the print spool file.

Comment: Can you please show me the detail how to parse the print spool file? Now I use the spool API to pause the print job; But I can not find a way to find out the real print count of the NUP job.

Comment: Thank you, I will have a try

Comment: We have tried many times, but we could still not get the right page count when printng N-up ppt.Have you ever solved this problem or Could you give us some guidance~Thank you

Comment: Thank you anyway,I will have a try.